# App is suspended when try renamed in Google Play

Tags: java, android, rename, publish, suspend

My English is very bad. I'm sorry if i made you uncomfortable because my litmited vocabulary.
Two years ago, i published my app in Google Play. Then, i wanted to rename it because updated app with new name, package and larger number version. But that day, my app was suspended.

This is gmail i received:
[image]

This is Google Play Console:
[image]

I think reason of the same 3 things:
+ My App use several image of game League Of Legend, but not code (my app is quiz app).
+ My new name app was "Million of questions LOL", i didn't know it same any name of famous app.
+ I failed to rename app, actually i can created diferrent 2 app.

Last 2 year, i didnot publish any app to Google Play. Well, before i do that, i'd like my english better and i must understand all terms of Google Play. But last 2 year, i'll not be better.
I didn't go to college and i was poor worker in Vietnam. But i want have several app in Google Play to show my friends. I love programming.
Thank you for reading...

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If your question is "What shall I do?" it is off-topic for not being programming related. But I think you should quickly find an English-speaking lawyer. As a side note, the pictures from League of Legend seem to be irrelevant.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is mostly a legal question and otherwise very opinion based what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your app got suspended because according to Google you were trying to Impersonate (copy) some other app. You should upload the same app with a different name and a different package name.